# SetDestination() sometimes does not work on NavMeshAgent with incomplete paths

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding, agent, navmesh

In most cases, when I call `SetDestination()` on a NavMeshAgent to go to a location that no complete path exists, the agent will go as close to the location as possible and then stop.

When I try to run `SetDestination()` continuously in an agent's `Update()` to an unreachable location, occasionally the agent just does not move at all. After calling a separate `SetDestination()` (to the same location) from a different script that sets a destination on mouseclick, the agent moves as close to the location, which did not occur when `SetDestination()` was called in `Update()`.

Why is this happening and when does unpredictable behavior occur with NavMeshAgents and `SetDestination()`?

Comment: if it cant get here it doesnt make a path - check it has a path

Comment: The agent typically goes as close to the destination as possible if it cannot reach its exact location.

Comment: calling set destination every frame is a bit excessive, it can still be working out a path from the last one

Comment: Wow, when I called SetDestination() once every 2 seconds instead, the agent always moved to the blocked-off location, although once every few playthroughs, the agent would halt temporarily when calculating a new path. The reason why I originally called SetDestination() every frame was because the obstacles in my game could change positions and I wanted the agents to use the shortest path every frame.

Comment: If the obstacles are marked properly the path should auto update

Comment: I had the same issue, and i noticed if SetDestination in the same frame as BuildNavMeshAsync, it won't work